# Can I send data via express next() function?

Tags: node.js, session, express, routes

I'm working on a webapp that requires atuhentication process and session management with express. I've done with the backend sessions stuff. Now i want to show on the UI the user who is signed in. privateContent is a function that verify if someone is logged in, Like so:

```
...
app.get( '/authRequired', queries.privateContent , routes.tasks );
...
```

Here is queries.privateContent:

```
...
exports.privateContent = function ( req, res, next ) {
  if ( req.session.user ) {
    var username = req.session.user.username;
    User.findOne( { 'username': username }, function ( err, obj ) {
      if ( true ) {
        next();
      } else {
        res.redirect('/');
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
};
...
```

What i want to know is: Am i able to send data like this? :

```
...
next( username );
...
```

if so, how can i retrieve it when routes.tasks render, if that happens as follows (i'm trying to get the data in the code below, but it does not work.):

```
...
exports.my_tasks = function ( req, res, data ) {
      console.log(data);
      res.render('tasks/tasks',
                  { title: 'Paraíso', controller: 'MyTasksController', user: data });
};
...
```

As you can guess, my intentions are to pass via next the current user who is signed in to the routing modules, so i can print the username in the UI using jade. 
Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In this case you have a few options (only use one of these!):

1. You can just access the req.session.user.username variable from your my_tasks route
2. You can use [res.locals](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals)
3. You can add data to the `req` object

In your exports.privateContent function, once a user is found in the database, you can simply add that data to the res.locals:

```
User.findOne( { 'username': username }, function ( err, obj ) {
  if ( true ) {
    // this variable will be available directly by the view
    res.locals.user = obj;

    // this will be added to the request object
    req.user = obj;

    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

Then in your exports.my_tasks route, `res.locals.user` will be whatever obj was in the middleware. You can then simply access that in the view as the variable `user`.

So, all together, you can access the data in your route in these ways:

```
exports.my_tasks = function ( req, res ) {
   res.render('tasks/tasks', {
     userFromReq: req.user, // this exists because you added in the middleware
     userFromSession: req.session.user, // this was already in the session, so you can access
     userFromRes: [DO NOT NEED TO DO THIS] // because res.locals are sent straight to the view (Jade).
   });
};
```

Comment: Can you give me better perspective which case is better to do. 
If I have {name: "Foo"} and want to give it middleware below current one.
Should I do it with: `req.myName = {name: "Foo"}` or with `res.locals = {name: "Foo"}`? 

Thank you in advance :)