# NodeJS - How to obtain the result to be used in another scope

Tags: node.js

I come from a PHP background and I'm kind of new to NodeJS.

I have a middleware that is doing a session check:

```
app.io.use(function(socket, next) {

  var redisClient = redis.createClient();

  redisClient.get('sess:1234', function(err, reply) {

  });
}
```

What I would like to do is to get the reply coming from redis query and use it in the middleware scope to check for some conditions, to assert an error or move along to the next step.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure which framework you are using,
but i think you can pass the query result to all consecutive middlewares and routes by attaching result to socket object like this

```
app.io.use(function(socket, next) {

  var redisClient = redis.createClient();

  redisClient.get('sess:1234', function(err, reply) {
       socket.queryResult = reply;
       next();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answered more in depth here: [Can I send data via express next() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793723/can-i-send-data-via-express-next-function)

In summation, it looks like you're using [Express.io](https://github.com/techpines/express.io) so I'm not certain about their syntax, but you are probably going to want to attach some data to the `req` object, which might be the `socket` object in Express.io.