# passing data between router controllers

Tags: node.js, express, routes

```
var self = this;
app.get("/attendees", function(request, response, next){
    self.authenticate(request, response, next);
}, function(request, response, next){
    self.service(request, response, next);
});
```

how can I pass the data between the router controllers, result of first controller and passing to the second controller.

I'm populating a custom property on request object at the moment, though it's not encouraged, and I'm trying to be safe using com.domain style. Please advise.

**P.S.** It's basically `request.user = {id: 1}` I'm populating after authentication on the server end.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for sessions, i.e. `req.session`.  Here is a tutorial: https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/

Comment: it seems good, but I'm kinda confused since I'm using token based authentication from the client, I validate each request against the token and call `next` on it for the next method to be called without maintaining any sessions, please help clear more on this a bit

Comment: check this out please. http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals in context of this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793723/can-i-send-data-via-express-next-function?rq=1 without maintaining a session

Comment: yes, local seems like the convention used, and I've adopted it

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the answer from this question

[Can I send data via express next() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793723/can-i-send-data-via-express-next-function?rq=1)

using `response.locals`

http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals